# How can I subtract 2 string type times in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'd like to be able to take one date/time in `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM` stored as a string and subtract them to get elapsed time in minutes.

For Example

the for entry  -> startdate: `1/26/2018 12:07`

and the entry -> enddate: `1/29/2018 8:27`

the time in between is `3 days, 3 hours, 41 minutes and 0 seconds` or `4541 minutes.`

Does `datetime / datediff` even support this function to find elapsed time?
If so how can I convert this string into datetime? Or is there another way?

Comment: Why are you storing Datetimes as strings rather than the datetime or timestamp format?  You really shouldn't be storing them as a string in the first place.

Comment: Store them in `DATETIME` format and you won't have this problem. The American-style slashy format is not computable without expensive conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `str_to_date()` and then some other functions.

```
select (to_seconds(str_to_date(enddate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')) - 
        to_seconds(str_to_date(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'))
       ) / 60
. . .
```